# What is the entry point file in LLVM and Clang?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang, llvm

I have setup a debugger with my Clang & LLVM projects. I want to make sure that it is working. So I want to put a breakpoint at a place where it will surely hit when I execute below command :

```
clang -S -emit-llvm foo.c
```

Please help me with the entrypoint function for these projects.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/893ac53afc1ae3d433fee2835a1c5db00369d0c4/clang/tools/driver/driver.cpp#L351

Comment: Thanks harry, this exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: If you are trying to debug clang using a debugger, keep in mind that clang will fork child processes to handle each source file provided in command line arguments, so the main process may 'skip' main parsing part from debugger's view.

Answer (score 3):

Your debugging problems are probably arising from the fact that `clang` is only a driver, which prepares elaborate command line and invoke the actual compiler.

When debugging Clang, I use the following trick:

- First append `-v` to your command line to see actual commands the driver running.
- Use this output to start the debugging session.